# Change ETH to Binance Chain network on sendTransaction with web3js

Tags: javascript, web3js, binance, metamask, wallet-connect

when site page download i have autoconnect MetamaskWallet, i need when page download auto change from Ethereum mainnet to Binance Chain to get donut in BNB in eth.sendTransaction i have error code: -32602, message: 'Invalid parameters: must provide an Ethereum address
with eth it works auto download donut with eth gas, can i auto change preferred mainnet BNB

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
          if (window.ethereum) {
            window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
            try {
              await ethereum.enable();
              initPayButton()
            } catch (err) {
              $('#status').html('User denied account access', err)
            }
          } else if (window.web3) {
            window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)
 window.web3 = new Web3('https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/')
            initPayButton()
          } else {
            $('#status').html('No Metamask (or other Web3 Provider) installed')
          }
        })

        const initPayButton = () => {
          $('.pay-button').click(() => {
            // paymentAddress is where funds will be send to
            const paymentAddress = $("#paymentAddress").val();
            const amountEth = "0.0001"

            web3.eth.sendTransaction({
//to: "binance_chain_adress_in_metamask_wallet", ///get error when i past address of another bnb wallet and click to button Donut! code: -32602, message: 'Invalid parameters: must provide an Ethereum address
              value: web3.utils.toWei(amountEth, 'ether'),
        from: paymentAddress
            }, (err, transactionId) => {
              if  (err) {
                console.log('Payment failed', err)
                $('#status').html('Payment failed')
              } else {
                console.log('Payment successful', transactionId)
                $('#status').html('Payment successful')
              }
            })
          })
        }
      </script>
        <div align="center">
     <input id="paymentAddress" type="text" value="enter_your_wallet_adress" />
        <button class="pay-button">Donut!</button>
        <div id="status"></div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

How can I change mainnet web3js for all users and get donuts in BNB when user will be on site show wallet Metamask with Binance chain and send eth.sendTransaction with BNB minimal gas not like eth network?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `currentProvider.request({ method: 'wallet_switchEthereumChain', params: [{ chainId: '0x61' }], // chainId must be in hexadecimal numbers});` to change users network and then start the transaction.

0x61 is the BSCTestnet, the ChainID listing can be found at: https://chainlist.org/